# Workaround for service to communicate with Quickbooks via QuickBooks SDK 13?

Tags: c#, asp.net, quickbooks

I've been working on a project for a customer for some time now, and we keep hitting this issue where QuickBooks and our application seem to be running in different user contexts or something of the sort.

This is a very simple Web Application that is using a basic Web Handler to take in requests, query QuickBooks, and send the Response with any results.

After many back and forths with Intuit, they made it quite clear that running the App as a service isn't suppported by QuickBooks.

We tried working around this by creating our own simple server with an HttpListener that would be able to handle the requests instead of IIS.  This seemed to make sense as we could run this within the same user context that QuickBooks is running in.  As of now I'm still having no luck with this approach.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're not having any luck with that approach? Error message? Other problem? Have you looked at the universally recommended approach for what you're doing (QuickBooks Web Connector) yet?

Comment: There error isn't all that helpful, it just says "Could not start QuickBooks."  This is an interesting error because if QuickBooks isn't running the error should say a path to the company file is needed if there isn't an instance of QuickBooks running.

I picked up this project in the making which was using the SDK as opposed to the web connector, and now that we have it basically complete using the SDK, I am just trying to find a solution to avoid having to rewrite the code to use the connector.  Thanks

Comment: Are you *positive* it's running as the same user, in a GUI session, with the same privileges as QuickBooks? QuickBooks often runs with elevated privileges, so make double sure. Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Thanks for the advise Keith.  I actually got on a WebEx with someone from Intuit and turns out unchecking "Keep QuickBooks running" (which we've tried multiple times in the past) in general preferences, along with adding a few lines to the qbsdk.ini file got it working.  Thanks!